# What is lucene skip list for?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, skip-lists

I'm studying lucene/elasticsearch internals, especially **storage structures**.
When lucene gets "terms" to find "docID",
I found it goes through *TermIndex->TermDictionary->Frequency*(.doc) (version 7.2)
.doc has each term's [posting list](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50PostingsFormat.html). .doc file also has [skip list](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/MultiLevelSkipListWriter.html) besides frequency data. In posting list, there are sorted docIDs.

My question is, what do they have skip list for? It seems what lucene search for is docID of a term. They should have some reason to have skip list and I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the lecture of Doug Cutter (founder of Lucene).
[pisa-dougcutter](http://lucene.sourceforge.net/talks/pisa/)

Documents are searched by DocID when each result of conditions on query are merged.